# Posting data using simple JSON - get an error - UnsupportedMediaTypeError: unsupported charset &quot;ISO-8859-1&quot;<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at jsonParser

Tags: java

I am trying to post data using the a simple JSON object.
First I tried reading the data from a file which was successful.
But when I tried posting data, I get the error.
Posted below is my code snippet for reference.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    POJO_PostReq Data = new POJO_PostReq();
    Data.setFirstName("Sambhaji");
    Data.setLastName("Yadav");
    Data.setDesignation("Tech Lead");
    Data.setMentorName("Deepak Channa");
    Data.setCourseName("API Testing");
    Data.setID("1706");
    Response Res = 
            given()
            .contentType("application/json")
            .body(Data)
    .when()
    .post("http://localhost:3000/friends");
    System.out.println("Status Code for Post Request =: " + Res.getStatusCode());
    System.out.println("Data posted is :");
    System.out.println(Res.asString());

}
```

Need help in resolving the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually connected with `Content-Type` or `Accept` headers. Try to add and an `Accept` header.

Check if the two headers are set correctly!